# Android - Ocultar botón que no recibe ningún valor

Tags: java, android, array, botón

Estoy haciendo una App de la carrera de universidad y una de las partes es un test con preguntas y 3-4-5 opciones de respuesta. Las respuestas están en botones que cada uno recibe un string desde un array. Ahora quiero que las preguntas de 3-4 respuestas oculten los botons que no reciben ningún valor desde el array. El valor de array vacío es "".

Está puesto así:

```
    private void preguntas() {
      String pregunta = preguntas_asignatura[pregunta_pantalla];
      final String[] parte_del_array = pregunta.split(";");

        TextView QuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(array_respuestas[0]);
        QuestionView.setText(parte_del_array[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { //empieza en 1 porque 0 es la pregunta

            Button boton_resp = (Button) findViewById(array_respuestas[i]);
            boton_resp.setText(parts[i]);
```

He intentado:

```
    if(botón.getText().equals(array_respuestas(parte_del_array[número_con_el_valor_vacío])){
       botón.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
```

Y otras formas parecidas pero no lo consigo.
¡¡Ayuda!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifica si el contenido es un string vacio "" y desactiva o esconde el botón:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { //empieza en 1 porque 0 es la pregunta
      Button boton_resp = (Button) findViewById(array_respuestas[i]);

      if(parts[i].trim().equals(""){
        boton_resp.setEnabled(false); //* Desactiva botón
        boton_resp.setVisibility(View.GONE); //*Si deseas puedes esconderlo.
      }else{
         //Si tiene contenido agrega texto a botón.
         boton_resp.setText(parts[i]); 
      }
      ...
      ...

}
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys!!! Llevaba días con esto y estaba a punto de dejarlo como estaba pero me lo has arreglado!! Sólo he tenido que añadirle dos cosas porque cuando salía una pregunta de 3-4 respuesta, a partir de esa ya todas salían con solo 3-4 botones, en else { botón_resp.setText(parts[i]); botón_resp.setEnabled(true); botón_resp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);} y esto ponerlo en cada uno de los botones justo antes del onClick(). Gracias Jorge!!!